# hive query to get json keys

Tags: json, hive

I have json as below in hive, each json has different keys, I am thinking to get all keys and use get_json_object to get values. So, Is there hive query get json keys out of it?

```
{
   "ts":"2016-07-27T13:06:18.089-05:00",
   "logVer":1,
   "msg":"123",
   "appData":{
      "appName":"test",
      "action":"SEARCH",
      "members":[
         {
            "id":"999043206",
            "dob":"02/23/1984"
         }
      ],
      "statusCode":200,
      "resultCode":0
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `REGEXP_REPLACE`!!

```sql
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(json,'\'(\\w+)\': \\w+,', '$1,')
      , '[{} ]', '')
FROM json_table
```